# Categories - how to alphabetically sort multiple root categories

Tags: category

I am successfully using the code provided by Marius (thank you Marius) to sort categories alphabetically.

[Categories - how to display in alphabetical order? (Programmatically)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/categories-how-to-display-in-alphabetical-order-programmatically)

```
<?php
//set error reporting to see if something is wrong.
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
//set developer mode for additional debug functionality
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//instantiate Mage_Core_Model_App;
Mage::app();
//set the initial parameters for the function
$root = 1;
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
//sort categories
orderCategories($root, $conn);

function orderCategories($parentId, $conn){
    //The position field is in the main category table
    //add prefix if you have one
    $table = 'catalog_category_entity';
    //get the children for a specific category id
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parentId);
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($collection as $category){
        //in case there are 2 categories with the same name we shouldn't skip them
        //but there shouldn't be
        $categories[$category->getName().'_'.$category->getId()] = $category->getId();
    }
    //sort categories by name
    ksort($categories);
    //set their position
    $position = 1;
    foreach ($categories as $name=>$id){
        $q = "UPDATE {$table} SET `position` = {$position} where `entity_id` = {$id}";
        $conn->query($q);
        $position++;
        //sort the current category children by calling the same function recursively
        orderCategories($id, $conn);
    }
}
```

I haven't modified the code at all and it works perfectly, but only on the first root category. I have multiple stores, each with it's own root category, so I would like to modify the code to work on all root categories or, preferably, be able to nominate an individual root category for sorting. Any help with achieving this will be much appreciated.

Edit: I have tried changing the value of $root to different category IDs (eg. $root = 5;) but it doesn't make any difference. Is category ID the correct value to be using for $root if I want to specify the root category for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and trying different scripts, I eventually found this one which works for me. It sorted all root and subcategories alphabetically in just a few seconds :)

[Magento Sort Categories Alphabetically using SQL Query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/magento-sort-categories-alphabetically-using-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Please use bellow code :

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class AR
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->sortOrderRootCategories();
    }

    public function sortOrderRootCategories()
    {
        $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        //The position field is in the main category table
        //add prefix if you have one
        $table = 'catalog_category_entity';
        //get the children for a specific category id
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $categories = array();
        foreach ($collection as $category){
            //in case there are 2 categories with the same name we shouldn't skip them
            //but there shouldn't be
            $categories[$category->getName().'_'.$category->getId()] = $category->getId();
        }
        //sort categories by name
        ksort($categories);
        //set their position
        $position = 1;
        foreach ($categories as $name=>$id){
            $q = "UPDATE {$table} SET `position` = {$position} where `entity_id` = {$id}";
            $conn->query($q);
            $position++;
            $this->orderCategories($parentId);
            //sort the current category children by calling the same function recursively
        }
    }

    public function orderCategories($parentId)
    {
        $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        //The position field is in the main category table
        //add prefix if you have one
        $table = 'catalog_category_entity';
        //get the children for a specific category id
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parentId);
        $categories = array();
        foreach ($collection as $category){
            //in case there are 2 categories with the same name we shouldn't skip them
            //but there shouldn't be
            $categories[$category->getName().'_'.$category->getId()] = $category->getId();
        }
        //sort categories by name
        ksort($categories);
        //set their position
        $position = 1;
        foreach ($categories as $name=>$id){
            $q = "UPDATE {$table} SET `position` = {$position} where `entity_id` = {$id}";
            $conn->query($q);
            $position++;
            //sort the current category children by calling the same function recursively
            $this->orderCategories($parentId);
        }
    }
}

$obj = new AR();
$obj->index();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abdul. Looks good but I got the following error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function orderCategories() in /home/captai22/devsite/categories.php on line 16

which makes me think that the top half of the code needs modifying also. I tried replacng

Comment: have you added old code also same file?

Comment: my code only for the multiple root categories sort order and orderCategories()  is different function

Comment: Oh so just add your code to the same file? OK I'll try that thanks :)

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I took your code Abdul and put it below Marius' code (provided in my question), ran it, reindexed, and there was no change to the categories order. And there were no errors either so I can't provide any more info I'm afraid. Any suggestions? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: i have updated ans so please add all code in new file eg.categories-ab.php and run

Comment: Many thanks Abdul. I tried it and got the following error:

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 308019200) (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/mysite/devsite/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 1046

There was no change to the categories but nothing was broken either. I am on a shared hosted server so it may be due to limited server resources. What do you think?

Comment: Is it possible to nominate one root category to be sorted at a time using perhaps root_category_id in Table core_store_group? This would consume fewer server resources.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: I appreciate your help Abdul, but nfortunately I'm not getting very far with this. All I need to do is specify a root category and perform the orderCategories () funtion on that root category. Marius' code works fine but only sorts subcategories within the first root category. If I change the value of $root (line 13) to another root category ID, eg $root = 5, the function does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't test it but this collection might give you all category collection with sorting by name.**

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addIsActiveFilter()
->addOrderField('name');
```

Comment: Thank you but I should've added that I'm PHP illiterate so can you to tell me exactly where to put the code and, if relevant, what to replace?

Comment: do you want to update in database or you just want collection?

Comment: I want to update in the database. Marius' code permanently sorts categories and subcategories alphabetically, but only works on a single root category. I am looking for the same thing but for multiple root categories.