# Sort Magento categories alphabetically using SQL query but for specific root category

Tags: magento-1.9, database, catalog, sql, sorting

I found this SQL query ([Magento Sort Categories Alphabetically using SQL Query](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/magento-sort-categories-alphabetically-using-sql-query)) and I've been successfully using it to re-sort all of our 30000+ categories but the problem I have is that it re-sorts all categories. I only have one category that needs re-sorting every now and then so my question is, how do I modify below query so that it only sorts all subcategories for a specific category (ID: 38744)?

```
SET @i=0;
SET @j=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AAA_NEW_POSITION;
CREATE TABLE AAA_NEW_POSITION SELECT e.entity_id AS 'entity_id',
    vn.value AS 'name',
    e.position AS 'old_position',
    @i:=@i + 1 AS 'new_position' FROM
    catalog_category_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_category_entity_varchar vn ON e.entity_id = vn.entity_id
        AND vn.attribute_id = 41
ORDER BY vn.value;

ALTER TABLE AAA_NEW_POSITION ORDER BY name;
UPDATE AAA_NEW_POSITION 
SET 
    new_position = @j:=@j + 1
ORDER BY name;

UPDATE catalog_category_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    AAA_NEW_POSITION np ON e.entity_id = np.entity_id 
SET 
    e.position = np.new_position;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AAA_NEW_POSITION;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the table with the join, you can add a condition to the `catalog_category_entity` table that specifies what the path looks like.  The first one you create would be `1/2/%`, after that, it depends on the order which you created the categories, so you will need to look at the path value for the root category that you are looking for:

```
select path from catalog_category_entity where entity_id = [the id of your category];
```

In the case that you want to filter by the *first root category*, it would look like this **(note the where condition in the second to last line)**:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA_NEW_POSITION SELECT e.entity_id AS 'entity_id',
    vn.value AS 'name',
    e.position AS 'old_position',
    @i:=@i + 1 AS 'new_position' FROM
    catalog_category_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_category_entity_varchar vn ON e.entity_id = vn.entity_id
        AND vn.attribute_id = 41
WHERE e.path like '1/2/%'
ORDER BY vn.value;
```

To resolve the null value issue, try the where condition below.  **Note that the position column is on the aaa_new_position table**

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    AAA_NEW_POSITION np ON e.entity_id = np.entity_id 
SET 
    e.position = np.new_position
WHERE np.new_position IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mtr.web, I appreciate it a lot. What I did (being an absolute amateur when it comes to MySQL) is run the first script you gave me which gave me ''1/38743/38744'' and then ran the query with the extra line and that worked!

Comment: I spoke a bit too soon as I just ran this again on our test database and it gives the following error; 23022 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1048 Column 'position' cannot be null (and this is repeated 64 times). Do you have any idea what this means?

Comment: I would try adding a `WHERE position IS NOT NULL` to the last update statement.  You may also be able to use it when you're populating the AAA_NEW_POSITION table, but it is perhaps better for debugging this way.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks again @mtr.web. I altered the last update statement to    UPDATE catalog_category_entity e LEFT JOIN AAA_NEW_POSITION np ON e.entity_id = np.entity_id SET e.position = np.new_position WHERE position IS NOT NULL  And this gave me the exact same error as before so I'm probably doing something wrong here.

Comment: @DennisGaasbeek, I edited the answer to show the full example.  My previous comment was incorrect, you will want to make sure the `np.new_position` value is not null.

Comment: You're awesome mtr.web, I think this did the trick! I just ran the query on our test database and there are no errors anymore: 8613 row(s) affected Rows matched: 21086  Changed: 8613  Warnings: 0. I will of course do some more tests but it seems to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks again for all of your help.